# não estou conseguindo publicar o meu repositorio no github

Tags: github

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

está dando esse erro

Comment: Bem vindo ao stackoverflow, poderia passar mais informações? configurou seu git corretamente?

Comment: sim mas agora não está dando de publicar o repositorio

Comment: O que exatamente está tentando fazer? um push?

Answer (score 0):

Para seu computador conseguir acessar seu repositório e fazer um push usando SSH por exemplo, ele precisa se autenticar com o github, para fazer isso ele precisa ter uma chave SSH que é informada sempre que você for fazer um push por exemplo.

Este seguinte link é do próprio Github com um artigo descrevendo todos os passos que você tem que fazer para criar a chave SSH, colocar ela na sua conta e testar a conexão.

https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh